# Ternary usage in FizzBuzz++ 1.5 (codeacademy)

Tags: recursion, ternary-operator

I've been running through codeacademy's tutorials and projects.  On FizzBuzz++ 1.5 they want us to re-write the "Wobble" function as Wob, using ternary operators.  I keep getting an error saying "missing operand" with the following code.  Also the +1 on the end of the return, how does that work, does javaScript store it as a temp value because it doesn't get assigned to any var.  Thanks for the help.  Code is below.

```
var Wibble = {

  Wobble: function(a, b) {
    if(a===b) 
        //if the variables are equal return 0
        return 0;
    else {
        //decrement the larger of the 2 values
        if (a>b) {
            a--;
        } else {
            b--;
        }
        //call this function again with the decremented values
        //once they are equal the functions will return up the stack
        //adding 1 to the return value for each recursion
        return Wibble.Wobble(a,b)+1;
    }
  },


//This is the line of code that doesn't want to function..
  Wob: function(a, b) {
    (a===b) ? return 0 :(a<b) ? return this.Wob(a--,b)+1 : return this.Wob(a,b--)+1;
    }
 };
```

Comment: I'm not javaScript guy, but maybe put the 2nd ternary operator in parenthesis. Also, do you want the 2nd ternary to be (a>b)?

Comment: I'd be a little more careful with your parenthesis.  Also, look at Edward Thompson's answer.  you should only use ternary operator to turn a condition into a value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following expression with the ternary operator:

```
result = (a) ? x : y;
```

is equivalent to the following:

```
if(a)
{
    result = x;
}
else
{
    result = y;
}
```

Note the syntactical difference, where in the ternary operator you are switching *in* the assignment, whereas in the `if` statement syntax, you are assigning *in* the switch.

That is to say that:

```
(a == b) ? return 0 : return 1;
```

is *not* equivalent to:

```
if(a == b)
    return 0;
else
    return 1;
```

Instead, you would want to write:

```
return (a == b) ? 0 : 1;
```

Comment: Wob: function(a,b){
      return (a===b)?0:((a>b)?this.Wob(--a,b)+1:this.Wob(a,--b)+1);
  }                                                                              -Your explanation was great!